# D-link Modem & Linksys Router Wrtg54

Tags: server, router, static-ip-address, linksys

I have recently brought a static ip address from my isp and i have a old computer to which i want to make my website live on internet i have read couple of forums and done research from it and nowhere i am to follow that.

I have a D-link modem and linksys router wrtg54 my isp have set up the static ip on d-link modem now i am confused what to do with the static ip as per my research many static ip are written on networks ip address,subnet,gateway and dns. I dont know how to set this up.

I had setup a static ip on my server computer which is 192.168.192.103 now i dont know what to do.Just for your refrence my Linksys router is configured on DHCP network.

I would really appreciate if someone can guide me or help me with a name who can setup this network thing so i can find the help for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, having a static IP does not resolve all the points for setting up a website, open to the public.

Consider the following points:

- Do you have a webserver running on your computer? 
  (see www[.]apachefriends.org/de/index.html for windows or help[.]ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html for Ubuntu)
- Does your ISP allow access on port 80?
  (this would change to 443 if you use https)
- Set the port forwarding on your router to the local machine
  (http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Linksys/WRT54G/HTTP.htm for more info)
- Get a domain (www.example.com) for your website
  (If you registered already a domain, you have to change the target IP to your fixed IP which you received from your ISP)

Try to work this through and don't stop asking!

Comment: I have a web server running on windows server 2008 r2 entp version not apache or ubuntu. I have written confirmation from my isp as well checked my ports are opened.i dont need a domain at this point i just want to use my externally for website and ftp only.